# Assessing the citation rank of a conference

Tags: citations, conference

How can I determine how much is a specific conference (in ICT field) cited ?
There are conferences that are quite influential with respect to that, and others which are less. How can I find that information about a specific conference ?
BR
Ilja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google scholar has a search engine for venues. You cannot see how many citations a venue has, but they show you the h-index and the h5-index (i.e., h-index considering the papers published in the last 5 years only).

Here is the link:
https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_venues&vq=human+computer+interaction&btnG=

Comment: Your search only gives rankings for venues where the search term appears verbatim in the title.  The categorical search is more inclusive; for example: https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_humancomputerinteraction